# How to correctly package Python3 app with subpackages

Tags: python, python-import, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

I have a package, `s3_backend`, which contains a module `api.py`, and a subpackage `util`, which itself contains 5 modules. I would like to package it up and upload it to PyPI so people can `pip install package` and use the scripting api, `api.py`, in the top-level package. Both packages (`s3_backend` and 's3_backend.util') include _init__.py files.

The whole project is held in a directory names `project` with the following structure

```
project
    |- s3_backend (package)
        |- __init__.py
        |- util (package)
            |- __init__.py
            |- module1.py
            |...
            |- module5.py
        |- api.py
    |- setup.py
```

`api.py` itself imports `modules1-4`.

Locally, from within `project`, I can do 
    import api
    api.func1()...
With no errors. When I uploaded the package to TestPyPI, and installed the package in a virtualenv in a new directory, I run into problems that trace back to the import statement in `api.py` that imports `modules1-4` from the subpackage `s3_backend.util`.

This line 
    from util import module1, module2, module3, module4
Throws this error
    No module names "util"
When I run this command
    from s3_backend import util

I can successfully

```
import s3_backend
```

and

```
help(s3_backend)
```

shows

```
api.py
util (package)
```

The contents of my setup.py are shown below. What is the proper way of handling the subpackages in my setup.py, and am I writing my import statements wrong?

For fixes, I have tried replacing

```
from util import ...
```

with

```
from .util import ...
```

and

```
from s3_backend.util import ...
```

but those caused problems locally.

Source code for setup.py:

```
# project/setup.py
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
  name='s3_backend',
  version='0.1.7',
  license='MIT',
  description='scripting api for file upload to s3',
  author='SkippyElvis',
  author_email='Skippy@Elvis.com',
  url='https://github.com/jackhwolf/s3_backend',
  keywords=['aws', 's3', 'file upload'],
  packages=['s3_backend', 's3_backend.util'],
  classifiers=[
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
  ],
)
```

Import statement in api.py:

```
from util import module1, module2, module3, module4
```

Please let me know if there is anything else you need to help me out. Thanks!

SkippyElvis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try using setuptools instead? The find_packages function works wonderfully as long as you have an **init**.py file in each folder you'd want to include.

Here's what you'd need to use in the setup.py

```
# project/setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
  name='s3_backend',
  version='0.1.7',
  license='MIT',
  description='scripting api for file upload to s3',
  author='SkippyElvis',
  author_email='Skippy@Elvis.com',
  url='https://github.com/jackhwolf/s3_backend',
  keywords=['aws', 's3', 'file upload'],
  packages=find_packages(),
  classifiers=[
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
  ],
)
```

Otherwise, you could macguyver a function to mimic find_packages. I wouldn't recommend that.

As for your imports, I am an advocate of using absolute, root-level imports. That enforces two things: it makes sure you're internally using your libraries the way your users will use it. Plus, it also makes sure you don't attempt to test your code from within some folder but instead invoke it through tests. The way it "enforces" that is, your absolute import wouldn't work from inside some folder. It would instead need to be invoked through an external file/function call.